# Voltage of oscillations in MCU

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, oscillator, crystal

I have this [ATmega MCU](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf). The XTAL1 input voltage specification (Table 29-1, page 383) is VIH1. Does this specification apply to the crystal?

I measured the voltages on the pins of the crystal and found they are 0.7 V to GND and 0.9 V to GND. The oscillations are fine and the device is working well.

I'd like to understand the values given in the table with respect to the crystal oscillation amplitude.

If the input supply to the MCU is 3.3 V and this XTAL's pins internal circuitry is connected to the inverter (whose power supply rails are 3.3 V), I expect to see oscillations of 3.3 V. Why is it not so?

Comment: The output from the oscillator is commonly an internal voltage lower than the supply. So what you describe is perfectly normal.

Comment: @Lundin, thank you for your answer. So, you mean to say the output of the the MCU's internal (inverter) oscillator, right? In that case, why is the voltage lower than the power supply? How does it get lower?

Comment: If I understand the working of a crystal correctly, (please correct if I am wrong) --- There's ambient noise/thermal noise in the surroundings. So, once the MCU is powered-up, this noise is seen by the inverter and amplifies all the frequencies and is sent to the crystal. The crystal selects a particular frequency and then only allows this frequency to the inverter which further amplifies. So, what controls the amplification of this oscillation of frequencies @Lundin

Comment: From your question and comments, you're imagining this as a digital logic circuit. Always remember that digital electronics is merely convenient analogue electronics. Look at the logic specs: HIGH and LOW have ranges. The oscillator circuit is made from analogue transistors and the block diagram in the datasheet is a simplification of the resultant analogue circuit. Crystal oscillators using an inverter in analogue mode (which many logic families can't do) is very documented and you'll find well written application notes on it already published and free on the Internet with your answers there.

Comment: The capacitance of your probes could be altering the characteristics of the oscillator, too. The proper way to probe a crystal would be with a low-capacitance active probe, which is very expensive and probably not what you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the input supply to the MCU is 3.3 V and this XTAL's pins internal circuitry is connected to the inverter (whose power supply rails are 3.3 V), I expect to see oscillations of 3.3 V. Why is it not so?

Voltage levels are irrelevant for crystal oscillators. But designers tend to keep the amplitude low to lower the consumption. It's also good for the crystal: Since the drive power is in microwatts range high amplitudes may create excess vibration on the crystal and may result in permanent damage.

> I'd like to understand the values given in the table with respect to the crystal oscillation amplitude.

I think this applies to external clock input (pulses).

PS: Be careful when probing XTAL_IN or XTAL_OUT pin because the internal capacitance of the probe (5, 10, 30 pF or whatever) loads the crystal and may cause frequency shift or loop gain change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, when an external oscillator (powered by the same 3.3V as that of MCU), the output voltage of the oscillator pin should match the VIH values of the MCU, right?

Comment: But In that case, why is the voltage lower than the power supply? How does it get lower? If I understand the working of a crystal correctly, (please correct if I am wrong) --- There's ambient noise/thermal noise in the surroundings. So, once the MCU is powered-up, this noise is seen by the inverter and amplifies all the frequencies and is sent to the crystal. The crystal selects a particular frequency and then only allows this frequency to the inverter which further amplifies. So, what controls the amplification of this oscillation of frequencies

Comment: @Newbie For your first comment: Yes. oscillator modules generate pulses so if one is used the levels should be within the range. For your second comment: the oscillator (generally Pierce oscillator for CMOS devices) is designed to keep the oscillation amplitudes low. It's a tough job for the designers because 1) it should be wide bandwidth, and 2)the consumption should be kept low. I don't know the other details, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Just a small follow up- If I connect a 25MHz oscillator output pin to the XTAL1/XIN (the input pin of the MCU crystal input), I expect to see 25MHz sine wave oscillations on the oscillator output pin? Or square pulses? Any idea on this?

Comment: @Newbie Why would you even try to connect a 25 MHz crystal to that MCU or expect to see anything?

Comment: @Newbie assuming you are talking about pulse-outputting oscillator modules. I really can't give an exact answer but here's what I think about it: If you connect the output of a module to XIN then quite possibly you'll see pulses on XOUT because, normally, XTAL is the feedback element for the Pierce oscillator so in the absence of the crystal the oscillator will run open-loop, therefore output pulses. But this is not an exact answer. Just an assumption.

Comment: @Newbie as a follow-up: You need to select the clock type using the respective bits in the respective registers. So the hardware, with its clock selector, switches to respective circuitry for proper operation. If you select the crystal from software and apply pulses from a module it may not work properly, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications don't apply to crystal. They apply to external logic level clock when the oscillator is not used.

If the input supply to MCU is 3.3V, it does not mean the oscillator works at 3.3V supply. Even if it did, oscillations would not have 3.3V amplitude. The oscillator may be and often is far more complex than just an inverter powered by 3.3V.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, when an external oscillator (powered by the same 3.3V as that of MCU), the output voltage of the oscillator should match the VIH values, right? Also, could you tell me what's the logic behind this less voltage of oscillation on the pins of crystal? The internal inverter is powered by 3.3V. So, that inverter should operate in the linear region for us to get lesser voltages than 3.3V? In that case, the voltage on the pins of crystal can be anything but not 3.3V as the inverter would be saturated?

Comment: You say the internal inverter is powered by 3.3V, but you have no knowledge or proof it is, in fact your measurements of voltage on crystal pins indicate the oscillator is not powered by 3.3V.

Comment: yes. I am assuming the inverter is connected to 3.3V. I am not sure. Just curious to know how it is happening?

Comment: Don't assume anything and there might be no way of knowing how Atmel designed their on-chip crystal oscillator. It might not be even Atmel IP but something they licenced from someone else so you will only get enough info how to use it properly, and you don't get any trade secret info how it really works, as it is not important. It is not an inverter, it just is drawn as inverter for simplified model. In real life it may have circuits such as automatic gain control to guarantee it is able to start-up and run in many difficult situations.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the clarification.